# Visual Studio 2019 debugger steps into header file instead of cpp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, header, visual-studio-2019

I have created a small c++ application with a header file, a cpp file, and a main function.
I expected that the header file would be an `interface`, that would just define my functions and properties, but the cpp file would be the one to implement.

However when I create my files, in my `main` function I have a breakpoint and try to step into my method, it just takes me straight to the header file definition instead of the implementing cpp file. Here is my code:

```
//header file
#pragma once
#include <string>
#include <SQLAPI.h>

class DbConnection
{
    public:
    int Id, Age;
    std::string Name;

    void ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName) { }
    void Retrieve(const std::string table) { }
};
```

Here is my cpp file:

```
#include "DbConnection.h"
#include <string>
#include <SQLAPI.h>
#include <iostream>

SAConnection sqlCon;
SACommand sqlCmd(&sqlCon);

int Id, Age;
std::string Name;

void ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName)
{
    sqlCon.Connect(
        databaseName,
        ",
        ",
        SA_SQLServer_Client);
}
void Retrieve(const std::string table)
{
    //code to retrieve data
    std::cout << "success";
}
```

My main function which is in a separate cpp file. I set a breakpoint and attempt to step into the method `Retrieve` and it takes me to the header file instead of the cpp. Any help with debugging is appreciated.

```
#include "DbConnection.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    DbConnection con;

    con.ConnectToDatabase(
       "databaseParameter");
    
    con.Retrieve("tableParameter");

    return 0;
}
```

I assume it is one of two things, either my debugger in visual studio 2019 is not set to the proper setting, or it has to do with how my `#include "DbConnection.h"` statements are included in both cpp files.

Comment: The debugger is correct. `void ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName)
{` in your cpp file is a free function. And has nothing to do with the `DbConnection` class.

Comment: Okay, do I need to specify the `DbConnection` class in my cpp file?

Comment: Not a class member function. A regular function as you would create in the `c` language which does not have classes.

Comment: To make it a class member you need (in your cpp file): `void DbConnection::ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName) { ...` however then you will have linker errors for 2 definitions since you defined ConnectToDatabase() in the header inside the class.

Comment: Yeah I am seeing the errors. Not sure if theyre linkers, they just say name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name

Comment: Remove the definition from the header. Change `void ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName) { }` to `void ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName);` in the header.

Comment: That didnt work.

Comment: You probably have other bugs that we can't see.

Comment: Thanks @drescherjm I had a typo, I had `DBConnection::method` instead of `DbConnection::method`. Thanks for your help. A silly mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You have to write in the cpp file

   void DbConnection::ConnectToDatabase(const std::string databaseName)
   {
   ...
   }

and so for the Retrieve function to tell the compiler that this is the function of the class.

2. You actually implemented the function in the header file when you put {} after the function declaration.

Comment: Oh my god I had a typo. I had `DBConnection::` instead of `DbConnection` my bad. Thanks.